# google ads API , CONTAINS ANY is not a valid operator to use with 'ad_group.name' in WHERE clause

Tags: google-ads-api

I am trying to fetch google Adwords reporting data (clicks,cost..etc) of specific addGroup with Google Ads Query Language buts saying CONTAINS ANY is not a valid operator to use with 'ad_group.name',
here is my query

```
"query": "SELECT ad_group.name, metrics.impressions,metrics.clicks FROM ad_group where ad_group.name CONTAINS ANY ('pmp')"
```

I need to fetch similar addgroup by name similar to SQL like '%%',
there is a LIKE command in GAQL but its working like = , eg for add group = 'test-exam'
this works

```
"query": "SELECT ad_group.name, metrics.impressions,metrics.clicks FROM ad_group where ad_group.name LIKE ('test-exam')"
```

but this returns nothing

```
"query": "SELECT ad_group.name, metrics.impressions,metrics.clicks FROM ad_group where ad_group.name CONTAINS ANY ('test')"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the SQL percentage syntax for the LIKE statement in GAQL too.

So:

```
SELECT ad_group.name, metrics.impressions,metrics.clicks 
FROM ad_group 
WHERE ad_group.name LIKE '%test-exam%'
```

This works for me.
I think 'CONTAINS' only works with the older AdWords API.